# Does elementary OS run on Dell XPS 13?

Tags: system-installation

after great experiences with elementary OS on my desktop pc, I would love to have it on my laptop as well. I'm planing to buy an Dell XPS 13 (the old version without the sick display) and would like to know if any of you guys have run this combination?
Btw: Is there any kind of list, on which devices elementary run stable?

Answer (score 2):

elementary OS is made on top of Ubuntu, so any hardware that runs Ubuntu shouldn't have problems.

There's a list of ["Ubuntu Certified Hardware"](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/models/?query=&category=Laptop&level=Any&release=14.04%20LTS&vendors=Dell) and the Dell XPS 13 is listed.